# Can we undelete the "Learning Regular Expressions" question? It has a great answer that should stay around

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

There once was a question called [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4736/1983854) that I just noticed that got removed. It was initially closed as "not constructive" (Nov'11) and then removed (Dec'14).

It is a pity, since it contains one of the better regex answers ever, [the one by Greg Bacon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/1983854) (261 votes after 35K views).

I agree it is a broad question, but since the information it contains is quite productive, wouldn't it be good to have it reopened or at least undeleted? I really think we are missing the point if we allow the system lose good pieces of information.

Also, the removed left few linked questions quite orphan, for example:

- [How do I learn regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/465119/1983854) (closed as duplicate)

Comment: Do you want all 38 answers undeleted or just the one you like?

Comment: @HansPassant To me, the *relevant* answer is the one I by Greg Bacon. Few of the answers were already removed before the removal of the question and I see some others that also should. But anyway, I think that is not that important. The key point here is to avoid good content to be lost, so anything that prevents that is fine to me (just undeleting this answer, copying it somewhere else, etc).

Comment: Well, surely the intention of the delete voters was to get rid of bad content.  That question has a disproportionate amount of it.  Why don't you just use the site license and copy what you like?  Preserving it in, say, a blog post?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A historical lock would be inappropriate, since the information could never be improved or edited.

It's also inappropriate because this question does not meet the criteria for a historical lock:

- Good content that is off-topic
- No chance of needing to update
- Lots of inbound links that revolve around it
- Lots of views (hundreds of thousands, usually)
- lots of votes

On the other hand, this is a perfect candidate for a wiki-lock.  We keep the best answer, merge the good content from the other answers into it, and that answer can be updated without worrying about new answers being added.

I've gone ahead and updated the best answer with the information from other answers, have rewritten the question slightly, and undeleted it.

It's up to the community to keep it up to date.

Comment: This was fantastic. I am extremely thankful and I am sure thousands of new viewers will also be!

Comment: There's already [books to learn regexes](https://github.com/vhf/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md#regular-expressions) available... why must we catter the content?

Comment: @Braiam I don't know what you mean by 'catter the content'.

Comment: extra t. cater: to supply what is required or desired. I don't know why everything *must* be on SO? Is provided elsewhere, more complete and expanded, why keep it?

Comment: @Braiam You said 'catter', that's why I didn't understand you (note the extra 't').

Comment: I know, read the first two words of my response.

Comment: @Braiam is not about the books themselves, but about a very good answer that shouldn't be lost.

Comment: @Braiam: I find it difficult to believe that there are very many questions on SO at all that don't also have an answer in some book somewhere. Should we get rid of them as well? The idea is that SO is an information repository where we can find lots of good content. In order to maintain that, we should delete the bad info, and keep the good. That answer was good and therefore should be kept.

Comment: If we would remove everything which is also in books, StackOverflow would become a very empty place...

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be worth undeleting and then adding a historical lock.