# Migrating older Open Source licensing questions to OpenSource.SE

Tags: discussion, migration

I ran across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419923/can-gpl-be-re-licensed). It's got a nice answer, it's just way off-topic for SO. Yet, it's been undeleted now. I'm trying to head off a deletion war...

[This Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327056/can-we-rescue-the-information-in-this-question-somehow) proposed migrating it somewhere and OpenSource.SE obliged. It's [on-topic there](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/tour) and it should live there.

> understanding, applying, and complying with Free & Open licenses

We have several of these out there I suspect. I'd like to propose we annotate some of them here and perhaps get a mod to migrate them *en masse* to OpenSource (if such a thing is possible). This is a big win-win since we preserve things that would just be historically locked, but keep the value they hold in a place where people can still discuss them. I've built a small list but there's a lot of them we could potentially "give" the OpenSource.SE community

Per Martjin, I have also [asked the OS community if they would like them](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/768/would-opensource-like-some-other-reposted-so-questions)

Comment: Not even moderators can migrate old posts. You'd have to re-post them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah. Learned something there

Comment: And much more importantly, this is *not* something the Stack Overflow community can just decide. This is something OpenSource.SE must decide on, as we can't foist our content on them just like that. This is entirely the wrong place for this post.

Comment: In other words, **ask Open Source SE**. Don't give. It is *their site* and they need to decide what goes and what doesn't.

Comment: Will ask them directly

Comment: Moderators can't perform migrations on questions that are more than 60 days old, but the community team can. If Stack Overflow decides that they don't want these and are going to delete them, and Open Source *independently* decides that they do want them, then I would definitely ask a community team member to migrate them. It is better than a historical lock, and *way* better than losing the information forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, this can't work.

First of all, no-one can migrate posts older than 60 days, not even moderators. The only option you have for these posts is to *re-post them*.

But more importantly, Open Source SE is still in beta. This is their formative time, when the site is building up a community and decides what is on topic and what is not. For that very reason moderators are more conservative as to what can be migrated to such a site, even if not an old post. It is not up to us to tell them what posts fit on their site.

Rather than ask the Stack Overflow community, you should ask the Open Source SE site community. Post on [their Meta](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/) if they want any of these posts.

Comment: [Asked on Meta.OS](http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/768/would-opensource-like-some-other-reposted-so-questions) as requested

Comment: @Machavity Hi! I'm a mod on Open Source! If you would like, I can develop a comprehensive answer for guidelines on "transferring" information, as well as things that are on-topic and all. (I also saw your post on OS meta)

Comment: @Zizouz212 That would be great. Some cross-posted guidelines would help the process along

Comment: @Machavity I'm working right now, but I'll definitely try and get something up and about on both sites when I find the time :)